# mount -t cifs with krb5i

Tags: centos6, mount, cifs

I am trying to mount a windows 2008 R2 share on my centos6 64 server and am getting the following message as a response to the mount:

```
mount -t cifs //esb.local/dfs /mnt/win --verbose -o username=ESBSertal,password=MyPassword,domain=ESB,sec=krb5i

mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.50.121,unc=\\esb.local\dfs,sec=krb5i,ver=1,user=ESBSertal,domain=ESB,pass=********
mount error(126): Required key not available
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

how can I provide the missing key?

thank you for your support.

Comment: Not answering your question, but... Windows 2008 Server can act as an NFS server, which will be easier to set up in the GNU/Linux side and supports KRB5 as well. Also, it will perform better than a CIFS share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turns out, centOS can not handle DFS because of a bug in Windows 2008

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74423/why-could-mount-cifs-mount-an-empty-folder

the normal share variety works better.